# Nagios Hosts Down but services up

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I've got a couple of servers (ftp) where the host is blocking ICMP so its showing as down, but the services (like ftp) are up.

To stop the service complaining about the host being down i have acknowledged the problem. The issue i had was the other night the FTP service died, but we didn't get a notification about it .

How can i still get notifications about service status on a host that Nagios thinks is down, if i disable the active checks will this solve it?

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case I use an "dummy-check" for the host-check which always responds to up - and I only get the service-notifications.

tsg

Answer (score 3):

An example of what tsg is to add this to your commands.cfg file:

```
# NO PING CHECK
define command{
command_name    SUCCESS
command_line    $USER1$/check_dummy 0
}
```

Then edit your host definition and change the check_command from check-host-alive to SUCCESS.

This works in Nagios 3.1.2